# Probabilistic proof for "regularity"

Tags: pr.probability, harmonic-analysis, additive-combinatorics

[In an old post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9218/probabilistic-proofs-of-analytic-facts,), someone said that the Calderon-Zygmund decomposition "follows from a simple stopping time argument". I would like to see this probabilistic argument (should be something simple). I know that the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, wich is important in the usual proof, can be proved using probability theory and then... but is there a faster way?

Also (I do not know too much probability theory) Lebesgue theorem can be proved by a kind of "energy increment" method (it looks like a regularity result): some quantity is "incremented" until we get enough structure and the process can be stopped...(I am thinking also to Roth theorem). Is there a corespondence, or a probabilistic interpretation for this? That "stop" has something to do with "stopping time"? Another thing: is there a direct probabilistic proof of Roth theorem (not via Szemeredi theorem)?

Comment: I've heard this description of this proof independently of that post... my assumption was that "stopping time" was being used in a deterministic form. I'm curious if anyone has insight here.

I suppose  predictability is still a valid and interesting concept even when the filtration comes from a deterministic process.

Comment: The stopping time is with respect to the dyadic filtration on Euclidean space (so, in particular, not a filtration on a probability space).  See e.g. http://www.math.unm.edu/~crisp/papers/lectures.pdf or http://bigwww.epfl.ch/chaudhury/Dyadic_decompositions.pdf

Comment: Reading very fast the proof from the first document... it seems to me that the Lebesgue theorem is still present.